# Actualización de XAMPP a PHP 7

Tags: php, bootstrap, xampp

Quise actualizar php 5.6 a 7, pero al probar una web que desarrolle con php 5.6 y boostrapp 4.3 me doy cuenta que tiene problemas para abrir ventanas modales, ya que solo me abre 1 sola de varias que tengo en una tabla (las invoco desde include). Probé varias versiones desde 7.1 hasta la 8 y sucede lo mismo, la conexión a la BD funciona bien, hasta ahora el problema que encontré son las ventanas modales. Cuando vuelvo a la versión 5.6 de php el problema se soluciona. Además actualice phpmyadmin  a 4.9 pero sucede lo mismo. Ya probé cambiar la versión de bootstrap y no pasa nada. Acá va el código de los enlaces que llama a los modales,uno de los modales de ejemplo y la llamada por jquery:

```
<!-- enlaces a modales -->
<a href="#delete" class="delete" data-toggle="modal" data-id="<?php echo $id;?>"><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true" style="color: red;"></i></a>
<a href="#"  data-target="#editm" class="edit" data-toggle="modal" data-id='<?php echo $id; ?>' data-nombre='<?php echo $nombre;?>' data-desc="<?php echo $desc;?>" data-precio="<?php echo $precio;?>" data-categoria ="<?php echo $categoria;?>" data-idcat ="<?php echo $idcat;?>"><i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size: 18px;"></i></a>
<a href="#" data-target="#imagen" class="edit" data-toggle="modal" data-id="<?php echo $id;?>"><i class="fa fa-file-image-o" aria-hidden="true" ></i></a></td>                              
<!-- modal editar que recibe info via href-->
<div id="editm" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <form name="editar_producto" id="editar_producto" >
                <div class="modal-header bg-success bordered">                      
                    <h4 class="modal-title ml-auto text-white">Editar producto</h4>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">                    
                    <div class="form-group" >
                        <input type="hidden" name="edit_id" id="edit_id" >
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Producto</label>
                        <input type="text" name="edit_nombre" id="edit_nombre" placeholder="3-25 letras" maxlength="25" pattern="[A-Za-zñÑ ]{3,25}" class="form-control" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Descripcion</label>
                        <input type="text" name="edit_desc" maxlength="150" placeholder="10-150 letras" id="edit_desc" pattern="[A-Za-zñÑ,-/:() ]{10,150}" class="form-control" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Precio (max. 2 decimales)</label>
                        <input type="number" name="edit_precio" placeholder="$1.00-$9999" id="edit_precio" class="form-control" step="0.01" min="1" max="9999" required>
                    </div>  
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Categoria</label>
                        <input type="text" name="edit_categoria" id="edit_categoria" class="form-control" disabled style="border:none;text-align:center;">
                        <select id="nuevo_catg"  class="form-control" name="nuevo_catg" onchange="cambiar();"><option value="" selected disabled>Cambiar categoria</option>
                        <?php 
                        include '../conexion.php';
                        $query = $conexion -> query ("SELECT * FROM categoria");
                        while ($valores = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
                            echo '<option value ="'.$valores['id_categoria'].'">'.$valores['cat_nombre'].'</option>';
                            mysqli_close($conexion);
                        }
                        ?>
                        </select>
                        <input type="hidden" name="id_categoria" id="id_categoria" class="form-control" >
                    </div>  
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer bg-success">
                    <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" value="Cancelar">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="Guardar datos">
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<!-- llamada de modal via jquery -->
$('#editm').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
    var button = $(event.relatedTarget) 
    var nombre = button.data('nombre')
    $('#edit_nombre').val(nombre)
    var desc = button.data('desc') 
    $('#edit_desc').val(desc)
    var precio = button.data('precio') 
    $('#edit_precio').val(precio)
    var categoria= button.data('categoria') 
    $('#edit_categoria').val(categoria)
    var id = button.data('id')
    $('#edit_id').val(id)
    var idcat = button.data('idcat')
    $('#id_categoria').val(idcat)
});
```

Comment: la version de php no tienen nada que ver con bootstrap, si tus modales no se ejecutan correctamente tu problema tiene que ver con html o javascript, si es el html muy probablemente dentro de la lógica de php que haces el armado de tu html algo esta ocurriendo mal.

Answer (score 1):

ya encontré la solución, resulta que 2 de los modales contenían la función [eregi()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.eregi.php) de php5 que permite cargar imágenes desde un directorio, la cual ya no es soportada en php7.Al parecer producía algún tipo de conflicto con bootstrap y no me dejaba mostrar los modales en pantalla cuando presionaba los enlaces. Ahora me faltaría saber como reemplazar dicha función para que me pueda mostrar imágenes desde una carpeta local.